# Symfony2 pass whole entity object to path()

Tags: symfony

Why I need this?

When I want to change the route from `/news/{slug}` to `/news/{id}` for example, I need to replace all places where `path('news', {'slug': 'my-post'}` is called. I want to pass the entity like so `path('news', {'post': post})` and then change the route however I like. This will give me the flexibility to easily change the routes. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass eneity as param. `path` function takes only string and number arguments, because this function generate url based on routing.

How do you imagine passing object to browser url bar?

```
/news/"{object": std_what_the_@?}
```

Of course you can make [your own twig function](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html) and pass object to make your url.

This way you can check your object has slug property and choose your route and params. Anyway you have to do it myself.

I hope it help but your question is not clear...